# php form automatically gets logout just after signup

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have one sign up page where users sign up and after that it redirect to feed page of site but i want my users to enter directly to feed page with there login credential as a member as they have just signed up but just after signup it redirect to a page i want but as a guest . i dont know why it is automatically getting signed out just after signup. i dont want my member to put there login details again and again as they have just signed up so they should be able to view there profile without furthur entering there login credentials. here is my code

```
function signup($iid) {
    global $db, $client, $uhome, $config;

    if ($_POST['onpost']) {
    if ($_POST['iid']) {
    $res = sql_query("select * from ".tb()."invites where id='{$_POST['iid']}'");
    $invite = sql_fetch_array($res);
    if ($invite['id']) {
    if ($hold) {
    $hold = 0;
    if ($invite['email'] != $_POST['email']) {
                            $errors[] = t('You must use the Email address from which you received the invitation');
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            if ($hold) {
                die('<p>'.
                    t('Only invited people can Sign up this network. If you are invited, please click the link in the inviting email.').
                    '</p>');
            }

            if (!$_POST['agree_rules']) {
                $errors[] = t('You must agree to our rules for signing up');
            }

            //get_r(array('username','password','password2','email','agree','confirm_code','location'));
            if (strtolower($_COOKIE['cfm']) != strtolower($_POST['confirm_code'])) {
                $errors[] = t('The string you entered for the code verification did not match what was displayed');
            }
            $_POST['username'] = strtolower($_POST['username']);
            if (strlen($_POST['username']) < 4 || strlen($_POST['username']) > 18 || !ereg("^[0-9a-z]+$",$_POST['username'])) {
                $errors[] = t('Username').': '.t('from 4 to 18 characters, only 0-9,a-z');
            }
            if (ereg('<',$_POST['fullname'])) {
                $errors[] = 'Unavailable Full name format';
            }

            if (!$_POST['email'] || !$_POST['fullname'] || !$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'] ) {
                $errors[] = t('Please fill in all the required blanks');
            }
            else {
                for($i=1;$i<=7;$i++) {
                    $col = 'var'.$i;
                    $key = 'cf_var'.$i;
                    $key2 = 'cf_var_value'.$i;
                    $key3 = 'cf_var_des'.$i;
                    $key4 = 'cf_var_label'.$i;
                    $key5 = 'cf_var_required'.$i;
                    $ctype = get_gvar($key);
                    if ($ctype != 'disabled' && get_gvar($key5)) {
                        if (!strlen($_POST[$col])) {
                            $errors[] = t('Please fill in all the required blanks');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $_POST['email'])) {
                $errors[] = t('Unavailable email address');
            }

            $password = md5($_POST['password'].'jcow');
            $timeline = time();
            $res = sql_query("select * from `".tb()."accounts` where email='{$_POST['email']}'");
            if (sql_counts($res)) {
                $errors[] = t('You have registered with this email address before.');
            }
            $res = sql_query("select * from `".tb()."accounts` where username='{$_POST['username']}'");
            if (sql_counts($res)) {
                $errors[] = t('The Username has already been used');
            }

            if (!is_array($errors)) {
                $reg_code = '';
                $verify_note = '';
                // member
                if ($_POST['hide_age']) {
                    $hide_age = 1;
                }
                else {
                    $hide_age = 0;
                }
                $newss = get_rand(12);
                if (get_gvar('pm_enabled')) {
                    $member_disabled = 1;
                }
                else {
                    $member_disabled = 0;
                }
                sql_query("insert into `".tb()."accounts` (about_me,disabled,gender,location,birthyear,birthmonth,birthday,hide_age,password,email,username,fullname,created,lastlogin,ipaddress,var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,reg_code) values('{$_POST['about_me']}',$member_disabled,'{$_POST['gender']}','{$_POST['location']}','{$_POST['birthyear']}','{$_POST['birthmonth']}','{$_POST['birthday']}','{$hide_age}','$password','".$_POST['email']."','{$_POST['username']}','{$_POST['fullname']}',$timeline,$timeline,'{$client['ip']}','{$_POST['var1']}','{$_POST['var2']}','{$_POST['var3']}','{$_POST['var4']}','{$_POST['var5']}','{$_POST['var6']}','{$_POST['var7']}','{$reg_code}')");
                $uid = insert_id();

                if ($uid == 1) {
                    sql_query("update ".tb()."accounts set roles='3' where id='$uid'");
                }
                sql_query("insert into `".tb()."pages` (uid,uri,type) values($uid,'{$_POST['username']}','u')");
                $page_id = insert_id();
                if ($_POST['iid']) {
                    sql_query("update ".tb()."invites set status=1 where id='{$_POST['iid']}'");
                }

                stream_publish(t('Signed Up <br /><br /> <img src="'.uhome().'/1.png">'),'','',$uid,$page_id);
                // welcome email
                $welcome_email = nl2br(get_text('welcome_email'));
                $welcome_email = str_replace('%username%',$_POST['username'],$welcome_email);
                $welcome_email = str_replace('%email%',$_POST['email'],$welcome_email);
                $welcome_email = str_replace('%password%',$_POST['password'],$welcome_email);
                $welcome_email = str_replace('%sitelink%',url(uhome(),h(get_gvar('site_name')) ),$welcome_email);
                @jcow_mail($_POST['email'], 'Welcome to "'.h(get_gvar('site_name')).'"!', $verify_note.$welcome_email);
                $_SESSION['login_cd'] = 3;
                redirect(url('feed'));
                exit;
            }
            else {
                foreach ($errors as $error) {
                    $error_msg .= '<li>'.$error.'</li>';
                }
                sys_notice(t('Errors').':<ul>'.$error_msg.'</ul>');
            }
        }
        if ($iid) {
            $res = sql_query("select * from ".tb()."invites where id='{$iid}'");
            $invite = sql_fetch_array($res);
            if ($invite['id']) {
                $hold = 0;
                $use_i_email = t('You must use the Email address from which you received the invitation');
                $iid_field = '<input type="hidden" name="iid" value="'.$iid.'" />';
            }
        }
        if ($hold) {
            c(t('Sorry, only invited people can sign up'));
            stop_here();
        }

        set_title('Signup');
            if (get_gvar('pm_enabled')) {
                c('<strong>'.t('Join Us').'</strong><br />
                '.t('Membership pricing').':<ul>');
                if ($pm_1m = get_gvar('pm_1m')) {
                    c('<li>'.$pm_1m.' '.get_gvar('pm_currency').' '.t('Per month').'</li>');
                }
                if ($pm_3m = get_gvar('pm_3m')) {
                    c('<li>'.$pm_3m.' '.get_gvar('pm_currency').' '.t('Per Annua').'</li>');
                }
                if ($pm_12m = get_gvar('pm_12m')) {
                    c('<li>'.$pm_12m.' '.get_gvar('pm_currency').' '.t('Per Yeal').'</li>');
                }
                c('</ul>');
                section_close(t('Paid membership'));
            }
                    c('
    <script>
    $(document).ready( function(){
    objrow = $("tr.row1 td::first-child");
    objrow.attr("valign","top");
    objrow.attr("align","right");
    });
</script>
    <form method="post" action="'.url('member/signup').'" >
    <table class="stories">
    <tr class="table_line1">


    <td colspan="2">'.t('Passport').'</td></tr>
    <tr class="row1">
    <td>*'.t('Email Address').' '.$use_i_email.'</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="20" name="email"        value="'.h($_REQUEST['email']).'" class="fpost" style="width:180px" /><br /><span class="sub">('.$invite_msg.t("We won't display your Email Address.").')</span>
</tr>
    <tr class="row1">


    <td>*'.t('Username').'/'.t('Nickname').'</td><td>
    <input type="text" size="18" class="fpost" name="username" value="'.h($_REQUEST['username']).'" style="width:180px" /><br />
    <span class="sub">('.t('4 to 18 characters, made up of 0-9,a-z').')</span>
</tr>
    <tr class="row1">


    <td>*'.t('Password').'</td><td>
    <input type="password" name="password"  class="fpost" value="'.h($_REQUEST['password']).'" style="width:180px" />
</tr>
    <tr class="table_line1">


    <td colspan="2">'.t('Personal info').'</td></tr>
    <tr class="row1">
    <td>*'.t('Full Name').'</td><td>
    <input type="text" size="20" name="fullname" value="'.h($_REQUEST['fullname']).'"  class="fpost" style="width:180px" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row1">


    <td>*'.t('Birth').'</td><td>
                    <select name="birthyear" class="fpost">
                    ');
                    $year_from = date("Y",time()) - 8;
                    $year_to = date("Y",time()) - 100;
                    if ($_REQUEST['birthyear'])
                        $yearkey = $_REQUEST['birthyear'];
                    else
                        $yearkey = $year_from - 12;
                    for ($i=$year_from;$i>$year_to;$i--) {
                        $selected = '';
                        if ($yearkey == $i)
                            $selected = 'selected';
                        c('<option value="'.$i.'" '.$selected.'>'.$i.'</option>');
                    }
                    if ($row['hide_age']) $hide_age = 'checked';
                    c('
                    </select>
                    <select name="birthmonth" class="fpost">');
                    for ($i=1;$i<13;$i++) {
                        if ($i<10)$j='0'.$i;else $j=$i;$iss='';
                        if ($_REQUEST['birthmonth'] == $j) $iss='selected';
                        c('<option value="'.$j.'" '.$iss.' >'.$j.'</option>');
                    }
                    c('</select>
                    <select name="birthday" class="fpost">');
                    for ($i=1;$i<=31;$i++) {
                        if ($i<10)$j='0'.$i;else $j=$i;$iss='';
                        if ($_REQUEST['birthday'] == $j) $iss='selected';
                        c('<option value="'.$j.'" '.$iss.'>'.$j.'</option>');
                    }
                    c('</select><br />
                     <input type="checkbox" name="hide_age" value="1" '.$hide_age.' />'.t('Hide my age').'
                    </td></tr>');
                    if ($_REQUEST['gender'] == 1) {
                        $gender1 = 'checked';
                    }
                    elseif ($_REQUEST['gender'] == 2) {
                        $gender2 = 'checked';
                    }
                    else {
                        $gender0 = 'checked';
                    }
                    c('
                    <tr class="row1"><td>*'.t('Gender').'</td><td>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="1" '.$gender1.' />'.t('Male').' 
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="0" '.$gender0.' />'.t('Female').'
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="2" '.$gender2.' />'.t('Hide').'
                    </td></tr>');

                    c('<tr class="row1"><td>*'.t('Come from').'</td><td>
                    <select name="location" class="inputText">');
                    $locations = explode("\r\n",get_text('locations'));
                    $_REQUEST['location'] = trim($_REQUEST['location']);
                    foreach($locations as $location) {
                        if ($_REQUEST['location'] == trim($location)) {
                            $selected = 'selected';
                        }
                        else {
                            $selected = '';
                        }
                        c('<option value="'.$location.'" '.$selected.' >'.$location.'</option>');
                    }
                    c('</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row1">

    <td>'.t('About me').'</td><td>
                    <textarea rows="5" name="about_me">'.htmlspecialchars($client['about_me']).'</textarea></td></tr>'); 

                    // custom fields 
                    $profile = array();
                    for($i=1;$i<=7;$i++) {
                        $col = 'var'.$i;
                        $key = 'cf_var'.$i;
                        $key2 = 'cf_var_value'.$i;
                        $key3 = 'cf_var_des'.$i;
                        $key4 = 'cf_var_label'.$i;
                        $key5 = 'cf_var_required'.$i;
                        $ctype = get_gvar($key);
                        $value = get_gvar($key2);
                        $des = get_gvar($key3);
                        $label = get_gvar($key4);
                        $required = get_gvar($key5);
                        if ($required) $required = '*';
                        if ($ctype != 'disabled') {
                            if ($ctype == 'text') {
                                if (strlen($profile[$col])) {
                                    $value = htmlspecialchars($profile[$col]);
                                }
                                if (strlen($_POST[$col])) {
                                    $value = h($_POST[$col]);
                                }
                                c('<tr class="row1"><td>
                                '.$required.$label.'</td><td><input type="text" name="'.$col.'" value="'.$value.'" />
                                <br /><span class="sub">'.$des.'</span></td></tr>');
                            }
                            elseif ($ctype == 'textarea') {
                                if (strlen($profile[$col])) {
                                    $value = htmlspecialchars($profile[$col]);
                                }
                                if (strlen($_POST[$col])) {
                                    $value = h($_POST[$col]);
                                }
                                c('<tr class="row1"><td>'.$required.$label.'</td><td>
                                <textarea rows="3" name="'.$col.'" />'.$value.'</textarea><br />
                                <br /><span class="sub">'.$des.'</span></td></tr>');
                            }
                            elseif ($ctype == 'select_box') {
                                $tarr = explode("\r\n",$value);
                                c('<tr class="row1">
                                <td>'.$label.'</td><td>
                                <select name="'.$col.'">
                                ');
                                if (strlen($_POST[$col])) {
                                    $value = h($_POST[$col]);
                                }
                                foreach ($tarr as $val) {
                                    if ($val == $value) {
                                        $selected = 'selected';
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        $selected = '';
                                    }
                                    c('<option value="'.$val.'" '.$selected.'>'.$val.'</option>');
                                }
                                c('</select><br /><span class="sub">'.$des.'</span></td></tr>');
                            }
                        }
                    }
            c('
            <tr class="row2">
            <td colspan="2"><strong>'.t('Rules & Conditions').'</strong>
            <div style="width:700px;height:200px;overflow:scroll;border:white 2px solid;padding:5px;">
            '.nl2br(h(get_text('rules_conditions'))).'
            </div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row2">
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <input type="hidden" name="g" value="'.$_REQUEST['g'].'" />
            <input type="hidden" name="onpost" value="1" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="agree_rules" value="1" checked /> '.t('I have read, and agree to abide by the Rules & Conditions.').' 
                        <input type="submit" style="background:#5BA239;color:white;font-size:1.5em;font-weight:bold" value="'.t('Signup Now').'" />
                        </td></tr>


            </table>
        </form> 
            ');

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to regenerate the session prior to redirect. I use the following code on signup:

```
session_regenerate_id();
// workload
session_write_close();
session_regenerate_id(true);
header("Location: /dashboard");
```

Comment: please tell where to put this code so that after signup my user will go to feed page directly

Comment: It would be used where you have your current redirect and the workload to mail out the users information. - Removing the header() redirect in my code, of course.

Comment: i tried and its again getting me out . again it is asking login details

Comment: Are you setting session_start() at the beginning of your pages, and are you storing anything to enable a check on the logged user (aside from login_cd?

Comment: o.O... In order to use a session, you need to enable it with session_start(). This should be used throughout your site. You then have to create a string that will allow you to check for the current user of said session ie. $_SESSION['check_variable'] with a distinguishable variable for that user.

Comment: @nbelmont let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2775/discussion-between-sujit-tiwari-and-nbelmont)

Answer (score 0):

after

```
@jcow_mail($_POST['email'], 'Welcome to "'.h(get_gvar('site_name')).'"!', $verify_note.$welcome_email);
```

add this line

```
$_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
redirect(url('dashboard'),t('Congratulations! You have successfully signed up.')); 
exit;
```

that's it.